# How does Textbox show price correctly?

Tags: c#, textbox

I need to have a `Textbox` to show price; decimals like : `12,000,000 OR 1 000 (Price)`
with `MaskedTextBox` i get : 120,000,00 OR 100 0

I would gladly appreciate it if anyone can help..
 
Thank You in advance

Comment: Your requirement is not clear !!!

Comment: what help do you need in it? Drag and drop things are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code to `KeyUp` event handler of your `TextBox`

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        int valueBefore = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
        textBox1.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecimalFormat` like this :

```
Double number = Double.valueOf(text);

DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.00 EUR");
String credits = dec.format(number);

TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.creditsView);
tt.setText(credits);
```

Also, check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590718/how-to-use-decimalformat-to-format-money)

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 decimal a = 12000000;
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        //output=> 12000000

        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N"));
        //output=>12,000,000.00

        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N1"));
        //output=>12,000,000.0

        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N0"));
        //output=>12,000,000
```