# How to force two digit after decimal

Tags: java, android, floating-point, sharedpreferences

I have the following TextView which displays $0.00 all the time unless any calculation is done after a button click and saved to this TextView.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTotalAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$0.00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#00A21E"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTotal" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etToll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
                android:background="@drawable/calcbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calculate"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

When I run the app, it displays $0.0 (this would work, except I am working with dollars and cents and I would like it to show two digit after decimal unless both digits are 00)

I am using `SharedPreferences` and here are my code within the app:

`onCreate()`

```
float totalTollAmount = 0;
    tollAmount = (EditText) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.etToll); //where the amount is entered
    tollAmount.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalFilter(6, 2)});
    tvTotalAmountLabel = (TextView) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalAmount); //holding total amount
    if (Float.toString(prefs.getFloat("dblTollAmount", 0)) != "0.0") {
        tollAmount.setText(Float.toString(prefs.getFloat("dblTollAmount", 0)));
    }
    tvTotalAmountLabel.setText("$" + Float.toString(prefs.getFloat("totalTollAmount", 0))); //retrieves the total toll amount and displays

btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        strTollAmount = tollAmount.getText().toString();
        strInfName = nameOfInf.getText().toString();
        String k = "";
        if (strTollAmount.length() != 0 && strInfName.length() != 0) {
            float dblTollAmount = Float.parseFloat(strTollAmount);
            submitInfo(dblTollAmount);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

    private void submitInfo(float toll) {
        y = "TEST";
        if (y != null) {
            editor.putString("someId", y);
            totalTollAmount = round(toll + prefs.getFloat("totalTollAmount", 0));
            tvTotalAmountLabel.setText("$" + Float.toString(totalTollAmount));
            }
              else {
            editor.putString("someId", "");
        }
        editor.putString("previous-trip", y);
        editor.putFloat("totalTollAmount", round(totalTollAmount));
        //editor.commit(); removed on 8/3
        if (nameOfInf != null && nameOfInf.length() > 0) { // added on 8/3...
            //Clear out this value from Enter Data tab ONLY if Calculate happens
        }
        if (tollAmount != null && tollAmount.length() > 0) {
            //Clear out this value from the Enter Data tab ONLY if Calculate happens
        }
        editor.commit(); //added on 8/3
    }

private float round(float amount){
    return Float.parseFloat(new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(amount));
}
```

`onDestroy` method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("OnDestroy", "Logged");
    if(nameOfInf != null && nameOfInf.length() > 0) {
        editor.putString("strInfName", nameOfInf.getText().toString());
    }
    if(tollAmount != null && tollAmount.length() > 0) {
        editor.putFloat("dblTollAmount", Float.parseFloat(tollAmount.getText().toString()));
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

What it's suppose to do:
Each time I hit the `calculate` button the app should take what's on the EditText `etToll` and add to the value thats already on the TextView `tvTotalAmount` and it will continue to do so everytime.

Although the original value for the TextView is $0.00, it only shows $0.0. I would like to show two digit after the decimal on the EditText and TextView because I will be working with dollar and cent.

How can I fix the issue I am facing?

If the full code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: You've shown a lot of unnecessary code. Just google stuff like "decimal format TextView" or something. You'll find stuff like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8590737/645270). And **never** use floats with currencies. Use BigDecimal or integer. See my link for more info on all of this.

Comment: Look up `String.format()`. I suspect that is what you need!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Float to n decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this in your code

```
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String FormattedText=form.format(your value);
```

set it to Edittext..it will work

Comment: My app FC with that code. I am guessing I have to redo the entire codes to match what I am looking to achieve.