# Floating Point is not correct

Tags: android, floating-point

I am getting a value from server that is not containing any Floating point let say its 
1234 and have to cvonvert it in Floating value with 2 decimal point like 12.34.

Right now what i am doing is getting value storing it in float that convert the current value `1234` to `1234.0`
after that doing this

```
tempB=Math.floor(tempB)/100.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
RewardsBalance=df.format(tempB);
```

But with this i m having an issue that when i have value such that 1230 it results in 12.3 not that 12.30 
but when i have value 1234 it gives the desired result that is 12.34 
so what step i m missing any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.3 and 12.30 are the *same* value. The problem is not the value but the code that incorrectly converts the right *value* to the wrong *representation*. You probably want "###.00". With "#", zero shows as absent.

Comment: so you mean i should use format like "###.00" despite using ###.## ?

Comment: You should use '#' if you want a digit to appear unless it's a meaningless zero. You should use '0' if you want a digit to appear even if it's a meaningless zero. That's what the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) say (see the section labelled "Special Pattern Characters").

Answer (score 1):

Use this it will work

[Two digits after point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128389/how-to-force-two-digit-after-decimal/18128724#18128724)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String.format("%.2f", your_value);
```

It will do just like you want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tempB=Math.floor(tempB)/100.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.format(tempB);
```

it will work fine.